# Java ClassLoading load libraries

Tags: java

I've created my own classloader and it works for jar files without dependencies/libraries. Howerver, when i want to load a jar file that has dependencies, it fails load, because it does not load the dependencies.

How can i solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: no, just a standard java project

Comment: just as a suggestion try to use maven. if you have last version of netbeans , it would be easy to try